# SQL Compute expression

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Just have a quick question, I don't think it's possible after reading sql manual but thought to give it a try here...

Q. Can we use column number in compute expression instead of column name or alias after OF?
Something like e.g

```
COMPUTE SUM LABEL 'TOTAL' OF 2 ON JOB_ID;

BREAK ON JOB_ID SKIP 1;
COMPUTE SUM LABEL 'TOTAL' OF SALARY ON JOB_ID;
SELECT JOB_ID, LAST_NAME, SALARY
FROM EMP_DETAILS_VIEW
WHERE JOB_ID IN ('AC_MGR', 'SA_MAN')
ORDER BY JOB_ID, SALARY;
```

SQL reference manual list below

```
OF {expr|column|alias} ...
```

In the OF clause, you can refer to an expression or function reference in the SELECT statement by placing the expression or function reference in double quotes. Column names and aliases do not need quotes.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Oracle11g database.. sorry forgot to mention.. thought database type not necessary.

Comment: @homer `SQLPLUS` commands, work based on column names(or aliases) only. If it supported for Column numbers, it would be a conflict for further queries. So it really makes sense to support for only column names.!